# Gridview page index updating only when it feels like it

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that receives a data source with 8621 entries with the page size set to 20.  The first page is displayed exactly as it should be.  I click the link to display page 2, and it also displays as it should.  Anything after that however is still page 2.  So if I click the link to go to page 3, the paging control updates saying I am on page 3, but the data displayed is the data on page 2.  I know the gridview is getting all 8621 entries because if I change the page size to 200 it displays those 200.  Why would the gridview work correctly for some pages but not others?  Anyways, enough with my rambling, here is the code itself:

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<cb:SortedGridView ID="SearchUsersGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Email" 
  DefaultSortDirection="Ascending" DefaultSortExpression="Email"
  AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="true" Width="100%" SkinID="PagedList">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="In List">
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="IsInEmailList2" runat="server" checked='<%#IsInEmailList(Container.DataItem)%>' OnCheckedChanged="IsInEmailList_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:CheckBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="NameLink2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#GetEditUserUrl(Container.DataItem)%>'></asp:HyperLink>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="LastName">
  <HeaderStyle horizontalalign="Left" />
     <ItemStyle horizontalalign="Left" />
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="FullNameLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%#GetFullName(Container.DataItem)%>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
  <div align="center">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="noUsersFound" enableViewState="false" Text="No matching users found."/>
  </div>
 </EmptyDataTemplate>
 </cb:SortedGridView>
 </ajax:UpdatePanel>
```

and some relevant code behind:

```
    SearchUsersGrid.Visible = true;
    SearchUsersGrid.DataSourceID = "SearchUsersDs";
    SearchUsersGrid.DataBind();
```

and the data source itself

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SearchUsersDs" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="FindUsersByName" TypeName="Builder.Users.UserDataSource"
  SelectCountMethod="CountUsersByName" EnablePaging="True" SortParameterName="sortExpression" DataObjectTypeName="Builder.Users.User" DeleteMethod="Delete">
 <SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchText" Name="searchPattern" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchByDropDown" Name="searchField" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Object" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

There is no PageIndexChanged  event.  Any ideas?

Comment: Would seem irrelative but I think its important; Are you using UpdatePanel?

Comment: Yes, the gridview is wrapped in an updatepanel.  `<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">`  Added code to main post

Comment: Something tells me it's a data mis-align from `CountUsersByName` and `FindUsersByName`. Without seeing either of those functions, I can only assume.

Comment: @Brad, those are some rather large functions.  I'm going to go look for them, and post them when I find them

Comment: @CountMurphy: You don't necessarily have to post them, just make sure they concur with each other. Maybe unit test is in order? Or a demo console app to make sure that CountUsersByName==(FindUsersByName).count?

Comment: @CountMurphy, I guess there must be an exception on 3rd page of grid which you can see by commenting update panel or by viewing Error Console if you use FF.

Comment: @Waqas: Sadly there is no exception.

Comment: @Brad, FindUsersByName.count is 8621 where CountUsersByName seems to vary each time its run...what on earth is going on?

Comment: @CountMurphy: Looks like you found your problem. Now you need to work on what's being passed, and why they vary.

Comment: Looking more carefully at it, I believe you are right.  I wish you put that in an answer instead of a comment so I could give you credit for it.

Comment: @Brad: Question though, if it is the count why do the first two pages work?

Comment: @CountMurphy: Something tells me it's a collage of the filters you're using, the queries and the pagination. But again, only speculative. Maybe put some trace logs in the functions and see what you're getting for data and how the results are being rendered.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the differing Count function results and FindUsersByName.count.  That was a stupid coding error on my part.  But even with these values being the same, the gridview STILL wont go past the second page.  I've tried everything I can think of, short of sacrificing a young goat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue had to do with our production server.  for some reason the code works great on our production box (even with the same data).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the AJAX update panel and check if it works as expected.. Another problem might be that if you bind the Grid in page_load make sure it is not posted back everytime.. put it in

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 SearchUsersGrid.Visible = true;
    SearchUsersGrid.DataSourceID = "SearchUsersDs";
    SearchUsersGrid.DataBind();

}
```